# Hide div onclick not work

Tags: jquery, html

I can't hide a `<div>` using the `onclick` handler.

If I use this JavaScript:

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $("div#onlinefriends").fadeIn();
    $("div#srcfriend").hide();
});
```

it works and the `onlinefriends` div is shown and the `srcfriend` div disappears. Why doesn't this version work?

```
$("div#close").click(function(){
    $("div#onlinefriends").fadeIn();
    $("div#srcfriend").hide();
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="close" style="text-align:center; border:0;">
  <h4>No match found</h4>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give the full code? At least where you put the javascript code?

Comment: I found the problem, it's because  <div id="close"> apper after ajax load it from external php file. the "$(document).ready(function() {  " doesn't recognizes the id=close, do I have to include the js file inside the external php file or I have another way to make it?

Answer (score 1):

If your `#close` element is dynamically pulled into your DOM by AJAX...

```
$(document).on("click", "#close", function() {
    $("#onlinefriends").fadeIn();
    $("#srcfriend").hide();
});
```

Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Answer (score 0):

try this bro :)

HTML

```
<div id="close" style="text-align:center; border:0;">
 <h4>No match found</h4>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$( "#close" ).on( "click", function() {
 $("#close").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
HTML

```
<div id="close" style="text-align:center; border:0; background:red;"><h4>No match found</h4><br/></div>
<div id="onlinefriends" style="text-align:center; border:0; background:blue;"><h4>Online friends</h4></div>
<div id="srcfriend" style="text-align:center; border:0; background:orange;"><h4>Source friends</h4></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#onlinefriends").hide();
$("#close").click(function(){
    $("#onlinefriends").fadeIn();
    $("#srcfriend").hide();
});
```

[Live Example - JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TriStarGod/58Jvq/)

---

Update referring to OPs comment.
When you dynamically added

```
<div id="close"></div>
```

use event delegation with $.on

```
$(document).on("click", "#close", function(){
    alert( "Dynamic Link Active" );
});
```